# After updating json file with groovy, the file data contains extra curly brackets and "content" object

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

This is sort of data I got in my json file

```
{"globals":{"code":"1111","country_code":"8888","hits":80,"extra_hit":1,"keep_money":true},"time_window":{"from":"2020.12.14 08:40:00","to":"2020.12.14 08:45:00"},"car":{"have":"nope"}}
```

After I run it through this groovy code in jmeter:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput


def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parse(new File("C:/pathToFile/test.json"))

log.info(jsonSlurper.toString())


jsonSlurper.globals.hits = 70
jsonSlurper.time_window.from = "2020.12.14 08:42:00"
jsonSlurper.time_window.to = "2020.12.14 08:48:00"

def builder = new JsonBuilder(jsonSlurper)

log.info(builder.toString())

def json_str = JsonOutput.toJson(builder)
def json_beauty = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json_str)


log.info(json_beauty.toString())

File file = new File("C:/pathToFile/test.json")
file.write(json_beauty)
```

the json file is updated, but all data are wrapped in new object "content"

```
"content": {
        "globals": {
            "code":"1111",
            "country_code": "8888",
            "hits": 70,
            "extra_hit": 1,
            "keep_money": true
        },
        "time_window": {
            "from": "2020.12.14 08:42:00",
            "to": "2020.12.14 08:48:00"
        },
        "car": {
            "have": "nope"
        }
    }
}
```

How to avoid that wrapping into "content" object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying and pasting the code from Internet without having any idea what it is doing is not the best way to proceed, at some point you will end up running a [Barmin's patch](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13070857)

My expectation is that you're looking for [JsonBuilder.toPrettyString() function](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html#toPrettyString()) so basically everything which goes after this line:

```
def builder = new JsonBuilder(jsonSlurper)
```

can be replaced with:

```
new File("C:/pathToFile/test.json").text = builder.toPrettyString()
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: :) a lot of searching a lot of new stuff, but sometimes is nice to get a hint from someone more experienced. thanks, your answer worked as needed :)